# is there a more efficient way to count how many vowels in a string?

Tags: python

```
def processStrings(userPhrase):
    """ This function will accept the phrase as string and will count every 
        instance of vowel then return a dictionary with key:values of each 
        vowel and amount of occurrences in string.
    """

    vowelCount = {i:userPhrase.count(i) for i in 'AEIOU'}

    return (vowelCount)
```

I am new to StackOverflow and Programming. I wrote this function as part of small program for class and am now curious to know what the most efficient solution would be. We were told to demonstrate a strong understanding of applicable concepts in developing an efficient solution, as far as I can tell this has to pretty close since it uses a dictionary and the count() is supposed to be good. I am wondering if I missed something like in that it has to iterate over the entire phrase 5 times to get the values but I can't figure out if there is a better solution that would mean less processing time or memory usage say if I used the function for a much larger string and searched more than just vowels or something.

Comment: I think your question could get better answer on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) SE.

Comment: "most efficient" in what way? did you have performance issues? did your program crash on a big input? what's wrong with the solution you suggested?

Comment: See the comment that I wrote below Reblochon's answer

Comment: Do you want to count only uppercase vowels? How big the `userPhrase` can get? I'm trying to help you get better answers.

Comment: Yes, sorry I forgot to mention I guess that the user input will be formatted to upper just for the purpose of searching without having to find upper and lower.  I am new but catch on quick, I felt that this method I wrote would be the most efficient say for any reasonable user entered string length(user isn't going to write a whole book or a library worth of them).
What I wondered is if there is a more efficient solution for that size and would there be a better way if I were to use this to say find every vowel in a string the length of every book in a digital library or something silly.

Comment: or is there a way to iterate over the phrase only once but still get the count of each? As far as I can tell only way to do that would be to search each thing in the string 5 times at once using if elif to save the small amount of processing time from the times it catches a vowel and doesnt have to search all 5. but the tradeoff between that small savings vs what I wrote seems like its not worth the mention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will likely be more efficient using a `Counter`, then extracting the values for the vowels, and retuen them:

```
from collections import Counter

def count_vowels(phrase):
    """ accepts a string and counts the number of each vowels.
    returns a dictionary key --> values 
            of each vowel and their number of occurrences.
    """
    vowels = "aeiou"
    frequencies = Counter(phrase.lower())
    return {vowel: frequencies[vowel] for vowel in vowels}
```

#### as a one-liner:

(as suggested by @stevenRumbalski in the comments)

```
from collections import Counter

def count_vowels(phrase):
    """ accepts a string and counts the number of each vowels.
    returns a dictionary key --> values 
            of each vowel and their number of occurrences.
    """
    vowels = "aeiou"
    return Counter(c for c in phrase.lower() if c in vowels)
```

Comment: Or `return Counter(c for c in phrase.lower() if c in vowels)`

Comment: Yes, correct. I wanted to spell it out because the OP mentioned he was a beginner. I added your suggestion to the answer, thank you!

Comment: I ran both solutions with `timeit` and the OP's solution ran more than x4 faster than yours. It was tested on Python 3.6.3.

Comment: Yes, what size was your input?

Comment: If I read that right, counter is counting every object in the string, not just the vowels so wouldn't this get worse with bigger and bigger datasets? I amnot saying my code didn't work or wasn't efficient, I am just curious if there was a different, unknown to me yet way of doing this that would scale to any size dataset and say could be used to search for words in a book or whatever

Comment: It is hard to say without measuring; or without knowing the size of the dataset, and what the data looks like. FWIT, your solution is also going through each letter, but instead of counting them all, it checks them against a list; the number of operations remain.

Comment: Yah I figured though that if mine is checking every letter against a list i know the size of vs this ones checking if every letter is already in the list being built by counter then if it is not, adding it to list with a +1 to its counter then even if that letter comes up again it still has to first check if its in list then find out it is and still +=1 the counter for it. would be faster at almost any size and use less memory if that became a factor.

Comment: for small lists (5-10 elements), it probably doesn't matter much, and may be even faster; you'd have to measure.